# How to add a module to dnn published solution?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have a published dnn solution.i need to add a module to that solution.How it possible?

I just made a module in a fresh solution and pack it without publishing and install it in the published solution.But the problem is that there is no app_code directory for published solution.so there shows an error while deleting the app_code directory.because it cannot find the controller directory.if we need not the controller this concept work fine.but in my scenario i need database connection.so i need the controller.so is there any shortcut for implementing the app_code of the specific module to the published website.

Answer (score 0):

How did you develop the module? If you used my module development templates at http://christoctemplate.codeplex.com you will find that packaging and deploying modules is very easy to do across websites. Using the "APP_Code" approach can be more difficult if you are trying to deploy modules.